# How to embed Nuget in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, deployment, .net-4.5, nuget-package

I have a WPF Client application project (.Net Framework v4.5.2+). There are no pre-requisites at Client end to use the product. All the external references are stored in a folder and MSI installer copies the folder on client machine during installation.

For a feature, I am using Nuget package, but now the product expects the nuget package to be installed on client machine.

Can nuget be embedded into WPF application project in a way that client need not install it?

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: Just look at what assemblies are added with your NuGet package and then include those in your MSI, I am assuming you add them manually. Or download them from your server if you have that capability.

Comment: Agreed (with XAMIMAX).  Think of a NuGet package as a glorified Zip file.

Answer (score 0):

A NuGet package contains assemblies (DLLs) that are downloaded when you *build* your app. These assemblies should then be copied to the output folder of your compiled app together with all other assemblies that your app requires at runtime.

So you don't need to "install" the NuGet package on the client machine. You simply install it in your app (for example using the `Install-Package` CLI command) when you develop and build it and then it's part of the app that you deploy to the client machine.